# @MessagingGateway and values from properties

Tags: spring, spring-integration, messaging

Is it possible to set up a defaultReplyTimeout for a @MessagingGateway using properties?

```
@MessagingGateway(
    name = "name", 
    defaultRequestChannel = "channel", 
    errorChannel = "channel", defaultReplyTimeout=${myValue} )
```

defaultReplyTimeout=${myValue} is not valid because it is waiting a long value but maybe exists an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch!

Since all othe our annotations (`@ServiceActivator`, `@InboundChannelAdapter` etc.) support PP for their values (`autoStartup`, `phase` etc.), the `@MessagingGateway` as well as `@Gateway` should support that too.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue and we'll take care of that in the SI 4.2.

As a workaround you can achieve that only with the `<int:gateway>` XML `@Import`.

Comment: Thanks Artem!. I will wait for next version :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to notify. This has been fixed long time ago already: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3615